# How to retrieve get request value after submission

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 3 project and am trying to retrieve a value (`bedroomid`) from the request inside a controller action like this

```
$bedroomid = $request->query->get('bedroomid');
```

which works fine. Note that this is before `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` condition. The problem is after I submit the form, `$request->query->get('bedroomid');` returns empty value. I need this value to pass it to another action like this:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('epita_housing_orders_show', array('id' => $id, 'bedroom'=>$bedroomid));
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
         return $response;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Here is my controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/booking/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="studentbooking")
 */
public function studentBookingAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();      
    $role = $user->getRoles()[0];
    $listing = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Listing')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));

    $booking = new Booking($em, $id);
    $form = $this->createForm(BookingType::class, $booking);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $bedroomid = $request->query->get('bedroomid');
    $selectedbedroom = $em->getRepository('EpitaHousingBundle:Bedroom')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$bedroomid));

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

      if ($listing->getPropertytype()->getId() == 1) {
         $booking->setListing($listing);
         $em->persist($booking);
         $em->flush();
         $url = $this->generateUrl('epita_housing_orders_show', array('id' => $id));
        }
      else {
         $booking->setBedroom($selectedbedroom);
         $em->persist($booking); 
         $em->flush();
         $url = $this->generateUrl('epita_housing_orders_show', array('id' => $id, 'bedroom'=>$bedroomid));
      }
     $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
     return $response;
    } 
    return $this->render('EpitaHousingBundle:Student:confirmbookingpage.html.twig', array(
        'id'=>$id,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'listing' => $listing,
        'bedroomid' => $bedroomid,
    ));
}
```

The `confirmbookingpage.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'EpitaHousingBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
{% form_theme form 'EpitaHousingBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
   <div class="container text-center">   
       <style>
             .error-message{
                color: red;
            }
        </style> 
    <div class="row content"> 
         <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-10 well well-sm">          
        <div class="impinst" style="background-color:#9b3163; color:white;">
            <b> <u>Important Instructions</u> </b> 
        </div>    

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12" align="left">  
            <p>  
                The booking service is available to EPITA International Department Students only. 
                This is a free service from the airport to the EPITA campus and surrounding areas.</p>
            <p>Please do not fill this form if:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>You have not yet booked your flight tickets.</li>
                <li>You arrive within the next 72 hours. The airport pickup request must be made atleast 
                    72 hours before the request time.</li>
                <li>You do not want to use the airport pickup service.</li>
            </ul>
            <br>  
            <p>Please note:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>     
                    We may be unable to process your application for airport pickup if you request for a pickup on a non working day(weekends,
                    <br> National Holidays) or between 6PM and 8AM(any day). In such scenarios, we will inform you about the non-availability and provide <br> you with some alternatives. </li> 
                <li style="color:red;">You can cancel (due to technical issues: flight cancelled etc.) not less than 6 hours prior to your arrival time in Paris. If you do not<br>
                    show up at the airport or cancel too late, an 80-euros fee will be automatically charged.</li>   
                </ul>
            <br> 
                <p>For any questions, please do not hesitate to contact us at international@epita.fr</p>   
            </div> 
        </div>  
        <br>
        <div class="impinst" style="background-color:#9b3163; color:white;">
            <b> <u>Booking Details</u> </b> 
        </div> 
        <br><br> 
        {{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('studentbooking', {'id': id }), 'attr': {'class': 'studentbooking','novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}              
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-left">{{ form_label(form.arrivaldate, 'Booking From') }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">{{ form_widget(form.arrivaldate) }}</div> 
            <div class="col-sm-7 text-left">{{ form_errors(form.arrivaldate) }}</div> 
        </div>         
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-left">{{ form_label(form.bookeduntill, 'Booking Till') }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">{{ form_widget(form.bookeduntill) }}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 text-left">{{ form_errors(form.bookeduntill) }}</div> 
        </div>   
        <br>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-left"><b>Amount to be paid</b></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"><input type="text" name="rent" style="width:110%;margin-left:35px;" value="250" disabled="disabled"/></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Euros</div> 

        </div>       
        <br>  
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-left">        
            <b> By paying the booking fee, you will bring to an end to the process of your online booking. Your application will then be
            transferred to our board of examiners for processing.(You will not be able to modify your booking anymore)</b>          
        </div>
        </div>     
        <br> 

       {% if listing.propertytype.id == 1 %}
      <a href="{{ path('epita_housing_orders_show', {'listing':id,'id': id }) }}"> 
          <button type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button> 
      </a>  
      {% else %}
      <a href="{{ path('epita_housing_orders_show', {'bedroom' : bedroomid, 'id': id }) }}"> 
          <button type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button> 
      </a>    
      {% endif %}

        &nbsp;&nbsp;  
        <a href="{{ path('studentlistingview', {'id': id }) }}">    
                    <input type="submit" name = "cancel" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary"/> 
        </a> 
                    <input type="hidden" name = "bedroomid" value={{bedroomid}}/>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>      
        </div>          
   </div>           
{% endblock %}
```

This is the page which redirects me to studentbooking action:

```
{% if listing.propertytype.id == 1 %}
      <a href="{{ path('studentbooking', {'listing':id,'id': id }) }}"> 
          <button type="submit" name="approve" value="approve" class="btn btn-primary">Book Now</button> 
      </a>  
      {% else %}
      <a href="{{ path('studentbooking', {'bedroom' : bedroom.id, 'id': id }) }}"> 
{#          <input type="hidden" name="bedroomid" value={{ bedroom.id }}/>#}
          <button type="submit" name="approve" value="approve" class="btn btn-primary">Book Now</button> 
      </a>   

      {% endif %}
```

Updated Answer:

```
$form = $this->createForm(BookingType::class, $booking, array('empty_data' => $bedroomid));
```

Create Hiddenfield in Bookingformtype like below:

```
public $bedroomid;
public function __construct($bedroomid = array())
{
        $this->bedroomid = $bedroomid;
}        
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $this->bedroomid = $options['empty_data'];
    $builder->add('booking', HiddenType::class, array(    
        'data'=> $this->bedroomid,
        'required' => false,
    ));
   }
```

Try controller:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
       $bedroom = $form->getData()->getBedroom();
 }
```

Now inside submitt you get bedroom value...

Comment: Why don't you use VarDumper::dump($request) to see how your request looks like?

Comment: Can you provide full code of your action?

Comment: @Stephan I am able to get the desired value but before form submission, but not after

Comment: @Anton I've edited the post

Comment: @Somesh thanks man :)